# How to iterate through ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called SparseMatrix. It contains an ArrayList of Nodes (also class). I am wondering of how to iterate through the Array and access a value in Node. I have tried the following:

```
 //Assume that the member variables in SparseMatrix and Node are fully defined.
 class SparseMatrix {
     ArrayList filled_data_ = new ArrayList();
     //Constructor, setter (both work)

     // The problem is that I seem to not be allowed to use the operator[] on
     // this type of array.
     int get (int row, int column) {
         for (int i = 0; i < filled_data_.size(); i++){
             if (row * max_row + column == filled_data[i].getLocation()) {
                 return filled_data[i].getSize();
             }
         }
         return defualt_value_;
     }
 }
```

I will probably switch to static arrays (and remake it every time I add an object). If anyone has a solution, I would very much appreciate you sharing it with me. Also, thank you in advance for helping me.

Feel free to ask questions if you don't understand anything here.

Comment: You should be using generics, and you can't use [i] to get an element out of an ArrayList, you have to use .get(i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not use raw types. See this link for more info: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

The fix is to declare the type of object held by your array list. Change the declaration to:

```
 ArrayList<Node> filled_data_ = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can access each element in the array list using `filled_data_.get(i)` (as opposed to `filled_data_[i]`, which would work for a regular array).

```
`filled_data_.get(i)`
```

The above will return the element at index `i`. Documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. (I have experience with C++, so Java concepts is rather new to me.) I found a way to do this with static arrays (inefficient), so I will take this into account. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @diuqSehTnettiK no problem =]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming filled_data_ is a list that contains list of objects of a class named Node.

```
List<Nodes> filled_data_ = new ArrayList<>();
for (Node data : filled_data_) {
    data.getVariable1();
    data.getVariable2();
}
```

More info http://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

Comment: I didn't mention this, but I am not going to parse the entire ArrayList. Still, this is good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use generic, then you need to cast the object

```
//Assume that the member variables in SparseMatrix and Node are fully defined.
 class SparseMatrix {
 ArrayList filled_data_ = new ArrayList();
 //Constructor, setter (both work)

 // The problem is that I seem to not be allowed to use the operator[] on
 // this type of array.
 int get (int row, int column) {
     for (int i = 0; i < filled_data_.size(); i++){
         Node node = (Node)filled_data.get(i);
         if (row * max_row + column == node.getLocation()) {
             return node.getSize();
         }
     }
     return defualt_value_;
 }
```

}

Comment: That sounds interesting, please provide an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If array list contains `Nodes` which defines `getLocation()` you could use :

```
((Nodes)filled_data_.get(i)).getLocation()
```

You could also define

```
ArrayList<Nodes> filled_data_ = new ArrayList<Nodes>();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `ArrayList` object, you should specify the type of the contained elements with `<>` brackets. It is also good to keep the reference to the `List` interface - not `ArrayList` class. To iterate through such a collection, use `foreach` loop:

Here is an example of the Node class:

```
public class Node {
    private int value;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Node> filledData = new ArrayList<Node>();
        filledData.add(new Node(1));
        filledData.add(new Node(2));
        filledData.add(new Node(3));

        for (Node n : filledData) {
            System.out.println(n.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```